# Set encoding for output in R globally

Tags: r, encoding, output

I'd like `R` to render its whole output (both to the console and to files) in `UTF-8`. Is there a way to define the encoding for `R` output for a whole document?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're getting at comes out of `options` .  For example, here's part of the help page for `file` :

```
file(description = "", open = "", blocking = TRUE,
     encoding = getOption("encoding"), raw = FALSE)
```

So if you investigate setting  `options(encoding=your_choicehere)`  you may be all set.

Edit:  If you haven't already, be sure to set your `locale` to the language desired.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. However, when I try `options(encoding = "UTF-8"); mytext <- "this is my text"; Encoding(mytext)` I get the output `unknown`.

Comment: @AnjaM possibly not supported on your system? See `?connections`

Comment: `?connections` refers to `?iconv` where it's stated that "all R platforms support (...) "UTF-8"". Also, `iconvlist()` lists UTF-8 (and 349 other encodings).

Comment: You'll get the same "unknown" response when using the default `options(encoding='native.enc')` . I don't think "encoding does anything during a character `<-` operation.

Comment: So what exactly does `encoding` change? Would it influence the `print` operation?

Comment: From `?Encoding` : "ASCII strings will never be marked with a declared encoding, since their representation is the same in all supported encodings."

Comment: I see, this makes sense. When I type `test <- "üäß"; Encoding(test)` it gives me `latin1`. So there is no way to tell `R` that all `print` instructions should be automatically encoded as `UTF-8`?